# Vue Router previous page without reload

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to create a back button to go to the previous page using the vue-router in vuejs that would work exactly like the browser's back button.  The problem is, when using history mode for the router, when I do

```
this.$router.go(-1);
```

it actually refreshes the page, which is quite annoying, and the browser's back button does not.  If I remove history mode, it works as expected, exactly like the browser's back button.  However, in this case, I need to deal with the ugly hashtag in the URL.  Also, since I only need this button for a few pages, I could also use keep history mode, but instead of making the back button actually go to the previous page, I could toggle around some values to change which dynamic component is shown, but not actually change the current page.  However, if I do this, the browser's back button wouldn't work as expected anymore, since it clearly can't toggle the state.

Is there any way to make a button that works exactly as the browser's back button does?  As in, make a back button that does not refresh the page, not have a hashtag in the URL, and still work with the browser back buttons?

EDIT:
Was going to delete since I realised it's not a problem with the code, it's a problem with the testing, but I'll keep it here just in case it's useful to someone.  When I was going to my route with the back button, there was no button to go to that route, so I would need to directly enter it into the URL.  However, this effectively wipes all the stored states, so my back button didn't work properly.  If I navigated to that page from another page, then my back button worked as expected.

Comment: How about storing the `from` guard line in a store or variable and then make the route to go that old page? [Global Before Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards)

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate hitting the browser's back button directly with [`window.history.back()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API).

Answer (score 1):

Try like that

```js
this.$router.back()
```